# DATEDIFF in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Leetcode problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/
The solution that I don't understand:

```
SELECT
    weather.id AS 'Id'
FROM
    weather
        JOIN
    weather w ON DATEDIFF(weather.recordDate, w.recordDate) = 1
        AND weather.Temperature > w.Temperature
;
```

Here weather and w (Alias of weather) are the same tables and DATEDIFF is comparing dates but I don't understand this, If weather and w are the same tables then doesn't that mean that DATEDIFF is comparing the same rows. The solution is correct which means that both rows are not same how?

Comment: It is comparing the same column, sure. But not the same row.

Comment: @Shadow Why DATEDIFF is comparing different rows when the tables are the same?

Comment: Two different "copies" of the same data (in reality, these are not copies, but easier to imagine the outcome this way).

Comment: You'd better return all columns in the select result so you will see which rows were joined to each other, it should be more clear to understand.
Also DATEDIFF doesn't compare rows, it just subtracts two dates, as you had requirements "the previous date" so you had for all rows join rows of previous date, when weather.recordDate - w.recordDate = 1

Comment: @Shadow I still don't understand how it's comparing different rows when the tables are the same?

Comment: @Emilia-tan all the rows are compared to all the rows. But for the same rows the conditions `DATEDIFF(weather.recordDate, w.recordDate) = 1  AND weather.Temperature > w.Temperature` are not satisfied for sure so no row is joined with itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you alias both copies of the table:

```
SELECT w1.id
FROM weather w1 JOIN weather w2 
ON DATEDIFF(w1.recordDate, w2.recordDate) = 1 AND w1.Temperature > w2.Temperature;
```

What this query does is join every row of the table with every other row of the same table which has as `recordDate` the previous day and less `Temperature` and returns the `id` of the 1st copy (if the conditions are satisfied).
In fact all rows of the table are compared against all rows, but when it comes to the same rows they are rejected because for them the conditions fail.

Also, note that your query may return the same id more than once, because it could happen that for a row of the table there may exist more than 1 other rows where the date is 1 day less and the temperature is less.
So maybe you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.id
.....................
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is the same and the columns being compared are the same but not the same rows satisfy the conditions on both tables.

Simplistic put a table join is a internal product of the rows of the tables involved. Which means that a self join of a table with 3 rows will return 9 rows.

When you set conditions, the result set is filtered and only the combined rows that satisfy them will be returned. In the exercise, the conditions are a relation between the row of the first table instance and the second instance.